GARCH with exogenous variance regressor in python?
I'm using arch_model from the arch package to create GARCH models, but unfortunately, it only allows creating models with exogenous regressors (the x input) for the returns model, not for the variance model.
I need a package that allows the variance equation to be like:
h_new = omega + alpha * eps^2 + beta * h_old + X_1 * x_1 + X_2 * x_2 

Is there a package with this feature available? From what I've read this feature exists in EViews, R or OxMetrics, but not in any python package.
